# Discrete mathematics - tree problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Prove that a connected graph G = ( V, E ) is a tree, if | V | = 6 and |{ v ∈ V | deg( v ) = 1 }| = 4  and |{ v ∈ V | deg( v ) = 3 }| = 2

Comment: You would have to prove one of several characteristics. I would go with "G is connected and has no circles." I remember when proving these one can briefly explain how G looks like (maybe even draw it) to show it.

Comment: Do you see how to show that the graph has exactly five edges, joe?

Comment: @GerryMyerson.  No.

Comment: Cannot be done.  Requires 5 leaves.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: What? Why?

Comment: @William, it doesn't matter whether *you* know how to show the graph has exactly five edges; what matters is whether joe knows.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. A proof could have this overall structure:

> Either the two nodes of degree 3 are neighbors, or they are not.
>
> **Case 1.** If they are neighbors, then ... (bla bla ba) ... and therefore the graph is a tree.
>
> **Case 2.** If they are not neighbors, then ... (bla bla bla) ... which is a contradiction.

Don't hope to find a slick *generic* argument that you can use to prove tree-ness given a degree sequence. It only works at all in this particular case because the tree happens to be so small.

Comment: More precisely: For any tree with at least $3$ internal nodes, there is a non-tree graph with the same degree sequence. So saying whether something is a tree based on its degree sequence is in general futile.